# How to get Quantity selected by customer on Product Page. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, frontend

I want to get the Quantity of the **product** selected by **Customer** on the Product page [image: ma]

And also wan to get Qty and the product price on the **Grouped Product** explained in the image
[image]

Comment: If you want to get while add to cart you can get in post request or else you can get by jquery as well @AsadKhan

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran Sir how can I get this by Post?

Comment: Please be clear on the scope, since you've only mentioned as get that data whether it is an phtml or controller. Thanks

Comment: I want to get the quantity in `phtml` file can you please send me the code?

Comment: phtml in the sense you can get it using jquery, that would be easiest way